# Set binwidth in ggplot2

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I have a plot with a time vector on the x-axis and want to set the "binwidth" parameter to "1 day" or some other date-time-string, till now I calculate the seconds of "1 day" or "12 hours". Is there a function which interprets "1 day" as numeric like the function seq does with the "by" parameter?

```
times<-seq(as.POSIXct("2013-07-01 00:00:00",origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT"),
         as.POSIXct("2013-07-8 00:00:00",origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT"),by="1 day")

binwi<-as.numeric(times[2])-as.numeric(times[1])
df<-data.frame(times=sample(times,100,T))

p<-ggplot(df,aes(x=times,y=..count..)) 
p<-p + geom_bar(position = "identity",binwidth=binwi)
p
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @SimonO101, I edit my start post, I hope it is now clearer.

Comment: much clearer! Nice one

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at how `seq` handles `"1 day"` by using

```
debug(seq)
seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2000-01-10"),"1 day")
undebug(seq)
```

and then use the corresponding code for your problem.